# Is it possible to make a specific color of an image transparent in bokeh?

Tags: python, image, bokeh

I have a 2D array with three different values [-1,0,1]. I have specified a custom bokeh color palette to give each value a different color.

I overlay this three valued image onto another image with 256 gray values.

For visual purposes I want make all values of -1 in three valued image transparent, i.e. I want to give the image glyph multiple alpha values.

Is there a way to achieve this in bokeh?

Here is some example code of plotting an image with a color palette:
[bokeh color image example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify alpha in palettes:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.image(image=[[[-1, 0, 1],
                [1, -1, 0],
                [0, 1, -1]]],
        x=[0], y=[0], dw=[1], dh=[1],
        palette=['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'red', 'blue'])

show(p)
```

Comment: thanks, that's great. I still have a question, what does the tuple at the first position of the pallette list specify? Or how does the alpha specification work? I can enter any integer value and always get the same output image.

Comment: Huh, you're absolutely right - there seems to be a bug in Bokeh where it doesn't convert tuples to color strings. I've created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9951. You can use `'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'` instead - the alpha is a float number between 0 and 1.

Comment: I did `from bokeh.colors import RGB` and then `palette=[RGB(255,0,255,0.5), 'red', 'blue']` and it wokrs. Thank you!